# Is it okay to use django's auth_user model for storing user's info

Tags: django

If I am trying to create a login app for my project is it advisable to use auth_user as the model to store newly created user's in and just extend in in my signup app through:

```
from auth.models import User

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
```

Or is it better to create a custom model to store users in. Will what I have above even work? I'm sure the answer is either "of course, that's what it's there for" or "dear god why would you want to do that" but I don't know which.

Comment: Its a little blurry what else you want to achieve. Just authentication or do you want also save extra stuff for your users (profile information)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is meant to store the credentials of users that will be able to log into and use the system via normal Django auth mechanisms. If your project will use Django's auth then yes, `User` is the correct model to use.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. and if you want to store additional information of the user, you could create another model and a foreign key to the user model.